# Sheaf with support in closed subscheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes

Let $X=Spec A$ be an affine scheme and $Y\subseteq X$ a closed subscheme with unclusion $i:Y\hookrightarrow X$ defined by a coherent ideal $\mathscr{I}$. For a $\mathscr{O}_{X}$-module $\mathscr{F}$ the sheaf $\Gamma_{Y}\mathscr{F}$ is the kernel of the canonical map $\mathscr{F}\rightarrow j_{*}j^{-1}\mathscr{F}$, where $j:X\backslash Y\hookrightarrow Y$ is the canonical inclusion of the open complement of $Y$ into $X$, i.e. $\Gamma_{Y}\mathscr{F}$ can be viewed as the subsheaf of $\mathscr{F}$ of sections whose support is contained in $Y$.

In a book I am reading the following argument is made:

> If a local section $s\in \Gamma(U;i^{-1}\mathscr{F})$ ($U\subseteq Y$ open) satisfies $(i^{-1}\mathscr{I})s=0$, then $s$ lies in $\Gamma(U;i^{-1}\Gamma_{Y}\mathscr{F})$.

Now this looks rather weird to me. For if we take, say, the structure sheaf $\mathscr{O}_{X\backslash Y}$, then to me the extension $j_{!}\mathscr{F}$ by zero outside of $X\backslash Y$ looks very much like a $\mathscr{O}_{X}$-module the local section of which satisify $(i^{-1}\mathscr{I})s=0$. At the same time none of those local sections lie in $\Gamma(U;i^{-1}\Gamma_{Y}\mathscr{F})$ unless they are zero.

Are there any reasonable assumptions on $X,Y$ or $\mathscr{F}$ other that $X=Y$ and $\mathscr{F}=0$ that would make this argument work?

EDIT: It has been pointed out by Roland that this is not a counterexample. However I'd be glad if anyone could help me understand the argument or clarify under what conditions it works.

Comment: How can you multiply $s$ by $i^{-1}\mathscr I$? It seems to me that at the very least you need to assume that $\mathscr F$ is a sheaf of $\mathcal O_X$-modules, which the constant sheaf isn't.

Comment: That is true. For the sake of consistency I modified the question and the counterexample, taking your objection into account.

Comment: $U$ is an open subset of $X$ but you're taking the sections on $U$ of $i^{-1}\mathscr{F}$ (sheaf on $Y$)? Are you sure about both?

Comment: That's a typo. U is meant to be open in Y.

Comment: What book is it ? Isn't $\mathcal{F}$ supposed to be (quasi)-coherent ? In general, the extension by zero is not quasi-coherent.

Comment: The argument appears in Proposition 1.5.16, right before equation (1.5.5), of Hotta, Takeuchi Tanisaki: D-Modules, Perverse Sheaves, and Representation Theory. As far as I can see, no (quasi-)coherence has been assumed, but the situation is somewhat specific, so maybe I am missing some implicit assumption.

Comment: Actually, I am confused by your counter-example. If $s\in\Gamma(U,i^{-1}j_!\mathcal{O}_{X\setminus Y})$ then $s=0$ as $i^{-1}j_!=0$ and thus $s\in\Gamma(U,i^{-1}\Gamma_Y\mathcal{O}_{X\setminus Y})$. So I don't see how,  this is a counter-example.

Comment: I agree. In any case, I don't seem to have understood the situation well enough neither to prove nor disprove the statement. I would appreciate any kind of clarification.